# How do I append list items <li> from an Unordered list <ul> between four other Unordered lists based upon their content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a list of brand names that are dynamically pulled into page and need to be segmented between 4 lists based upon their brand name. For example one column will hold anything that begins with a number. The second column will hold all brands that begin with the letters A thru H. The third column I-P. The Fourth column Q-Z. I am currently trying to use the .map() function in jquery to traverse the list and pull items out and append to the respective list but am having some difficulty. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

(note: not actual brand list... Will have about 50 brands in final list.)

Here is my html:

```
<div class="brand-directory-body">
  <ul class="brand-directory-list" style="display:none;">
     <li class="brand">37 Signals</li>
     <li class="brand">Apple</li>
     <li class="brand">BMG</li>
     <li class="brand">Cartoon Network</li>
     <li class="brand">Disney</li>
     <li class="brand">ENews</li>
     <li class="brand">Nike</li>
     <li class="brand">Adidas</li>
     <li class="brand">Frito</li>
     <li class="brand">Coke</li>
     <li class="brand">Adobe</li>
     <li class="brand">Hostess</li>
     <li class="brand">Dominoes Pizza</li>
     <li class="brand">Honest Co</li>
     <li class="brand">Z Brand</li>
</ul>
<div class="brand-directory-column">
     <h3 class="column-title">#</h3>
     <ul class="brand-directory-list-num"></ul>
</div>
<div class="brand-directory-column">
     <h3 class="column-title">A-H</h3>
     <ul class="brand-directory-list-ah"></ul>
</div>
<div class="brand-directory-column">
     <h3 class="column-title">I-P</h3>
     <ul class="brand-directory-list-ip"></ul>
</div>
<div class="brand-directory-column">
     <h3 class="column-title">Q-Z</h3>
     <ul class="brand-directory-list-qz"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your current js code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var lists = {
    numbers: [],
    AH: [],
    IP: [],
    QZ: []
};

$('.brand').each(function () {
    var letter = $.text(this).substr(0, 1);

    if ( /\d/.test(letter) ) {
        lists.numbers.push(this);
    }
    else if ( /[a-h]/i.test(letter) ) {
        lists.AH.push(this);
    }
    else if ( /[i-p]/i.test(letter) ) {
        lists.IP.push(this);
    }
    else if ( /[q-z]/i.test(letter) ) {
        lists.QZ.push(this);
    }
});

$('.brand-directory-list-num').append( lists.numbers );
$('.brand-directory-list-ah').append( lists.AH );
$('.brand-directory-list-ip').append( lists.IP );
$('.brand-directory-list-qz').append( lists.QZ );
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q697n/

---

If you want to make the code a little [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)er, you can store the regular expressions in a map object:

```
var lists = {
    numbers: [],
    AH: [],
    IP: [],
    QZ: []
};

var map = {
    numbers: /\d/,
    AH: /[a-h]/i,
    IP: /[i-p]/i,
    QZ: /[q-z]/i
}

$('.brand').each(function () {

    var el = this, letter = $.text(this).substr(0, 1);

    $.each(map, function (key, regex) {
        if ( regex.test(letter) ) {
            lists[key].push(el);
            return false;
        }
    });
});

$('.brand-directory-list-num').append( lists.numbers );
$('.brand-directory-list-ah').append( lists.AH );
$('.brand-directory-list-ip').append( lists.IP );
$('.brand-directory-list-qz').append( lists.QZ );
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q697n/1/

Comment: Wow you are awesome! Works perfectly!